# How is this definite integral solved: $\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}{e^x\over(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, exponential-function

$$\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}{e^x\over(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}dx $$
Tried partially integrating, had no luck.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says it's $π/3$ http://bit.ly/1FCNzkB

Comment: Hint: Contour integration

Comment: This is for high school such techniques are not taught there..

Comment: @Enigma What contour would you propose? Maybe a rectangle with height going to infinity, width  $2 \sqrt{3}$ and reinforcement on with the top edge.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a trick.

You may just write
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}{e^x\over(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}dx &=\int_{-\sqrt3}^{0}{e^x\over(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}dx+\int_{0}^{\sqrt3}{e^x\over(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\sqrt3}{e^{-x}\over(e^{-x}+1)(x^2+1)}dx+\int_{0}^{\sqrt3}{e^x\over(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\sqrt3}{1\over(e^{x}+1)(x^2+1)}dx+\int_{0}^{\sqrt3}{e^x\over(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\sqrt3}{(1+e^{x})\over(e^{x}+1)(x^2+1)}dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{\sqrt3}{1\over x^2+1}dx\\\\
&=\left[\arctan x\right]_0^{\sqrt3}\\\\
&=\frac \pi3.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Basically , what you did here you applied the sub $u=-x$...

Comment: @Tolaso Basic tools are sometimes powerful ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is another way to solve. Let
$$ A=\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}{e^x\over(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}dx, B=\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}{1\over(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}dx. $$ 
Clearly
$$ A+B=\int_{-\sqrt3}^{\sqrt3}\frac{1}{x^2+1}=2\frac{\pi}{3}.$$
Changing variable $x\to -x$, it is easy to get $A=B$. Thus
$$ A=\frac{\pi}{3}. $$